# Baking a HABTM-association

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-bake

I'm getting the following error and can't see why. I can see that the PodcastsUser is not a table... I baked the whole application with the DB below –
Im getting the error just when accessing`/Podcasts/view/*Nr*`, `index` etc is fine. THANK YOU!

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PodcastsUser.podcast_id' in 'on clause'
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `PodcastsUser`.`users_id`, `PodcastsUser`.`podcasts_id` 
FROM `podcaster`.`users` 
AS `User` 
JOIN `podcaster`.`podcasts_users` 
AS `PodcastsUser` 
ON (`PodcastsUser`.`podcast_id` = 1 
AND `PodcastsUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
```

this is my HABTM-association:
[image]

**Model/User.php**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Podcast' => array(
        'className' => 'Podcast',
        'joinTable' => 'podcasts_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'podcast_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

**Model/Podcast.php**

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'podcasts_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'podcast_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

---EDIT---
The **PodcastsController** `view` action:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Podcast->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid podcast'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Podcast.' . $this->Podcast->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('podcast', $this->Podcast->find('first', $options));
}
```

Comment: If it's just in that particular view, maybe the problem is how you're retrieving the object. Can you post the view action code?

Comment: the same happens when I want to access `/users/view/1` (so, the User Model).